# Request GET parameters in Django

Tags: django, http, url, request

I have a incoming request that looks like this, its from a third part so it´s out of my hands.

`/external/endpoint?PRN=1234567&INPUT=1111;ABCDEF&CUSTOMER=555454545`

When I print the request parameters in `request.GET` this is what I get. The `INPUT` parameter is chopped off into two different ones.

```
Incoming dict: {u'INPUT': [u'1111'], u'ABCDEF': [u''],u'CUSTOMER': [u'555454545'], u'PRN': [u'1234567']}
```

I could hack the request URL myself but I was surprised by the default behavior of the request object. Thought it only divided the parameters by "&". Anyone else seen this or know if this is supposed to happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to W3, ";" is actually the preferred parameter separator for a URI.

http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/appendix/notes.html#h-B.2.2

> B.2.2 Ampersands in URI attribute values
>
> The URI that is constructed when a form is submitted may be used as an
>   anchor-style link (e.g., the href attribute for the A element).
>   Unfortunately, the use of the "&" character to separate form fields
>   interacts with its use in SGML attribute values to delimit character
>   entity references. For example, to use the URI `http://host/?x=1&y=2`
>   as a linking URI, it must be written `<A href="http://host/?x=1&#38;y=2">` or 
>   `<A href="http://host/?x=1&amp;y=2">`.
>
> We recommend that HTTP server implementors, and in particular, CGI
>   implementors support the use of ";" in place of "&" to save authors
>   the trouble of escaping "&" characters in this manner.

Comment: Thanks a lot, that answers it then! Poorly choice of dividers from the provider.

Comment: Semicolons as a separator are enforced by [Python's urlparse module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/urlparse.html#urlparse.parse_qs), on which Django's QueryDict's rely.